# Equivalent of AD_PERFORMANCE_REPORT in Google Ads API?

Tags: java, api, ads, google-ads-api

I am using Adwords API. But the support for Adwords will end in 2022. I want to migrate to new Google Ads API. I want to know the equivalent of AD_PERFORMANCE_REPORT(which was in Adwords) in Google Ads.

For example,
the equivalent for KEYWORD_PERFORMANCE_REPORT is keyword_view.

I tried to find it a lot but couldn't get it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for ad_group_ad.

Here's a query I use:

```
SELECT campaign.name, ad_group.name, customer.id, customer.descriptive_name,
                campaign.advertising_channel_type,
                segments.date,
                ad_group_ad.ad.expanded_text_ad.headline_part1,
                ad_group_ad.ad.expanded_text_ad.headline_part2, 
                ad_group_ad.ad.expanded_text_ad.headline_part3,
                ad_group_ad.ad.expanded_text_ad.description,
                ad_group_ad.ad.expanded_text_ad.description2,
                customer.currency_code,
                metrics.average_cpc,
                ad_group_ad.ad.shopping_product_ad,
                metrics.cost_micros,
                metrics.impressions,
                metrics.clicks,
                metrics.ctr,
                metrics.conversions
                FROM ad_group_ad
                WHERE segments.date BETWEEN {date_range}
                AND campaign.advertising_channel_type = 'SEARCH'
                AND metrics.cost_micros > 0
                ORDER BY segments.date
```

Bear in mind, for shopping ads, you'll need to use shopping_performance_view.

Comment: One more thing, how to get the CreativeFinalUrls in the new API? Is there a documentation where all these are mentioned?

Comment: Yup, here: https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/reference/rpc/v8/overview

All resources are categorized in the menu on the left pane. Turn off your ad blocker!